# Replace part of a string with another string (missing first string)

Tags: c++

cin >> "You are very good."

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s;
    cin  >> s;

while (getline(cin, s))
{
    while (s.find("bad")!= string::npos)
         {
             s.replace(s.find("bad"), 3, "good");
         }
    cout << s << endl;

}
    return 0;
}
```

cout << "are very good."

Where is first word "You"? How should look correct code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cin >> s;` before the loop is reading the first word of the line and removing it from the input stream. Then `getline(cin, s)` reads the rest of the line. So the first time through the loop, `s` is just `are very bad`. You then replace `bad` with `good`, and the result is `are very good`.

There doesn't seem to be any reason for the `cin >> s;` line, so just remove it.